# Cannot mount USB HD ext4 on RPi 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, media-server

I am pretty new to Raspberry Pi and I am trying to permanently mount an external HD.  I am running Raspian on a Pi 3.  I have installed Plex and intend to use this drive, which already contains my media, as the drive for the server.

The drive is this type:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="extsmall" UUID="3721afc7-bdb1-4979-8349-abc18f378896" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="b71d3e39-01"
```

I ran the `sudo ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/` which returned this:

```
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Mar 28 22:01 3461-3439 -> ../../mmcblk0p1
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 28 22:01 3721afc7-bdb1-4979-8349-abc18f378896 -> ../../sda1
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Mar 28 22:01 540aa4bc-b2c7-4894-9f03-ffc7aabfc110 -> ../../mmcblk0p5
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Mar 28 22:01 91E2-DB03 -> ../../mmcblk0p6
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 15 Mar 28 22:01 e2b3289b-6c40-404a-9059-57813cce2039 -> ../../mmcblk0p7
```

I edited fstab by adding this line:

```
UUID=3721afc7-bdb1-4979-8349-abc18f378896    /mnt/usbstorage    ext4   nofail,uid=pi,gid=pi $
```

I still cannot see the HD when I run `cd /mnt/usbstorage` then `ls`.  In addition, I cannot see anything in that directory when running the GUI.

Comment: The output of `mount` with no arguments is more definitive than `cd ...; ls`.  I don't think `auto` is required as an option, but you could try it (since `noauto` is also an option, it's implied `auto` is for something).  You may want to check that before and after a call to `mount -a` (see `man mount` and `man fstab`). Although it's not related to your problem, you probably also want `async` and `noatime` with an ext4 fs.

Comment: Like I said, I'm new to Raspberry Pi. I'm only slightly less new to Linux, in general.  Can you provide some specific steps to follow?

Comment: Well, `sudo mount -a` should mount everything in fstab that *doesn't* have the `noauto` keyword.  I believe that's exactly what happens at boot (but the question then remains, what is `auto` for?).  Plain `mount` (you don't need `sudo`) will show everything that's mounted; it doesn't show UUIDs, but it will show the mount points (and the list should be easy enough to skim through).  So you can fiddle with fstab and use `sudo mount -a` and check with `mount` without having to reboot...

Comment: ...If the mounting doesn't happen, have a look at `journalctl | tail -n 40` right after you try to see if any errors are logged by the system.

Comment: I simply added `sudo mount -a` to fstab.  The only change to the output to `mount` is that the line `gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)` appears in the output before the change.  There are no errors logged from the `journalctl | tail -n 40` command.

Comment: *"I simply added sudo mount -a to fstab."* -> ??? **It's not a script, it's a configuration file.**  I think that will most likely be ignored.  The point about `sudo mount -a` was that **you can use it directly from the command line** to simulate the behaviour from boot and see if your fstab config is working the way you want.  **This way you do not have to edit fstab, reboot, ad infinitum.**

Comment: I see that.  Like I said, learning most of this for the first time.  I added `/dev/sda1    /mnt/usbstorage    ext4   nofail    0   0` to fstab and now I can see the media in that directory.  It seems to be working now.

Comment: If you were missing the `0 0` off the end that may be why -- like the spurious `mount -a`, it would just be ignored as malformed.  I'm not sure if it does that or just plain choke, but probably the former since that's more robust and if the system choked on fstab because of a typo in one line that could suck ;)

Comment: BTW Another thing you may want to think about is setting the 6th field to something other than 0 (probably 3, again see `man fstab`).  This will auto-fsck the partition before mounting.  If it was cleanly unmounted before, it won't take up any time (except every N mounts, this is an option set on the filesystem); if it wasn't, you probably want this to happen.

Comment: You should try to mount the drive from the command line before making that mount permanent in fstab.

Comment: You might try `findmnt` which gives a more readable, hierarchical list of mounted drives.